# Flutter: How to use new version of buttonColor in ThemeData which has been deprecated?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
ThemeData(
      buttonColor: Colors.white, 
),
```

How to use the new version for `buttonColor` in Flutter?

Comment: Check this for button themes: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons

Answer (score 2):

Flutter has deprecated buttonColor inside the ThemeData. I looked upon the documentation and it specifies that the button uses primary color define inside the ThemeData as default button color. But we sometimes need the colors of button to be different. For that you can use the below way. In your ThemeData function you can make these changes:

```
ThemeData(
      ...
      highlightColor: Colors.white, //Using highlight color as button color
      ...
),
```

And, wherever you defined the color of button you can make these changes:

```
ElevatedButton(
      ...
      style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor:
              MaterialStateProperty.all(context.theme.highlightColor),
      ),
      ...
),
```

Answer (score -2):

For Floating Action Button,

```
ThemeData(
    floatingActionButtonTheme: const FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
    ),
);
```